# 2000 jeep grand Cherokee blinkers and flashers not working

Tags: electrical, jeep, wiring, grand-cherokee, flasher

I have recently purchased a 2000 Jeep grand Cherokee Limited. The blinkers were not working when I bought it was told it was probably just a relay. I have replaced the relay check the fuse check and replaced any bad bulbs replaced the multifunction switch and still have no blinkers or flashers. I don’t have hundreds of dollars to take it to a mechanic, can you help please?

Comment: Do the hazards work? Are there any other electrical problems?

Comment: No other electrical problems just the blinkers and emergency flashers are not working

Comment: You said you replaced the fuse, was the fuse actually blown? Did you test the fuse you took out?